# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, pickle

I use Python3.6 and this code occurs error

```
with open('val_image_id2feature.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    val_image_id2feature = pickle.load(f)
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

if I add `encoding='latin1'` or `encoding='bytes'` as follows, new issues occur

```
with open('val_image_id2feature.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    val_image_id2feature = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

> _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

How to deal with it?

Comment: What was the data pickled with? Also Python3?

Comment: I am not sure, I downloaded from github, if it is pickled with Python2.7, how to do?